# How can I embed YouTube videos as a custom playlist and make them play in a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to embed some YouTube videos in a website in a form of a playlist. I want them to play as a playlist, looping all the videos without waiting time in between.

So far I have this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WTybilbbFqw?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=PMIhuOOMLXs,yV8qytGjsFc,WTybilbbFqw"></iframe>
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `rel=0` into the line.
Like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WTybilbbFqw?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&playlist=PMIhuOOMLXs,yV8qytGjsFc,WTybilbbFqw"></iframe>
```

As a standard thing, the video will reset. If rel = 1 which is default, then the video is stopped/paused to display the related video list..